# How to install Git Large File Storage on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, github, git-lfs, large-file-support

According to its [doc](https://help.github.com/articles/installing-git-large-file-storage/), double-click should be enough. But when I opened git bash and ran `git lfs init`, it doesn't work:

```
$ git lfs init
git: 'lfs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Comment: try this then https://git-lfs.github.com/?utm_source=github_site&utm_medium=learnmore_link&utm_campaign=gitlfs

Comment: should be `git lfs install`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only reason why "git lfs" would not be a git command would be because the `git-lfs.exe` hasn't been put in your `%PATH%`.

That is what the `git-lfs-windows-amd64-0.5.3\install.bat` is supposed to do.

```sh
set GIT_LFS_BIN_PATH="%LOCALAPPDATA%\GitLFS\bin"
IF EXIST %GIT_LFS_BIN_PATH% GOTO DIRECTORY_EXISTS
mkdir %GIT_LFS_BIN_PATH%
set "path=%PATH%;%GIT_LFS_BIN_PATH:"=%"
```

So:

- Make sure install.bat was successfully executed
- Check the content of "`%LOCALAPPDATA%\GitLFS\bin`"
- make sure to open a new CMD Windows
- Check your `%PATH%` environment variable

Comment: This should either be in the git-lfs docs or added to the installer, as all Windows users encounter this.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding my 2c in case someone lands on this page..

The easiest (and I believe most "correct") option to install LFS on Windows is to use the windows' built-in `winget` package manager

```
winget install -e --id GitHub.GitLFS
```

I was getting the same error as you after simply running the downloaded installer, however the winget command fixed it for me.

PS. Even if you don't have `winget` - running `winget` will automatically install it from MS Store